# Where I can download Microsoft Enterprise Instrumentation Framework?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, enterprise, instrumentation

I'm trying to debug an legacy enterprise application that uses Microsoft Enterprise Instrumentation Framework but unfortunately I don't have that framework installed  in my PC and I can't find it. All links pointing to Microsoft Downloads are broken. Please help me...

Comment: EIF was replaced by the Logging and Instrumentation Application Block, which in turn was subsumed into Enterprise Library. Are the EIF dlls not on the deployed server?

Comment: @podiluska Do you think that a possible solution can be to copy EIF assemblies from the server to my local GAC?

Comment: It may work (or copy them to the bin folder of your app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from @podiluska solved this question, I copied the EIF libraries from server to my local GAC and it works. The situation was very particular due to a OS reinstall but staging and production environments were OK.